# What is the minimum number of things needed to declare you have a variety?

Tags: definition, philosophy

When people say things like "we have a wide variety of products" or "product x can run in a variety of modes", what is the lowest number of modes or products which one can comfortably call a variety?  Is having 2 things, a red and blue widget say,  a satisfactory quantity to call "a variety of widgets" ?  If not a simple number, perhaps it would be the level of differences between the things?  I could safely declare a variety of widgets (red and blue) but not a variety of products (I just have widgets). Thoughts?

Apologies if this is not really "mathematics" but you folk seem to be the perfect group and this sort of comes down to sets perhaps.

Comment: It's a language thing (and a marketing thing), not a mathematics thing. Marketers are (depending on country) allowed to say basically whatever they want. Especially when using vague words like "variety" and "many". So without reading minds, there is no way to know what they mean when they say it. Nor is it possible to tell whether they mean what they say.

Comment: This is maybe a question for "English Language and Usage".

Comment: @Arthur - I am sure they don't mean what they say....marketeers that is :)

Comment: This is clearly related to the [Sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox).

Comment: @Somos Ah yes I have also been considering (another marketing term) the use of "heaps of..." in descriptions and wondering what one could call a heap ... and when it doesn't conform to that description.  The Sorites paradox is very interesting - thanks

Comment: @Somos That post about the Sorites Paradox is very suitable for this query of mine.  Supervaluationism, hysteresis,  and consensus are all interesting resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is really an issue of language and psychology. For example, linguists have studied the different concepts and vocabulary that are used in different languages.

The mathematical approach would be to recognise that "wide variety" isn't well defined and either avoid it or say something like "For the purposes of this problem, I will treat *a wide variety of $x$* as meaning . . . " and proceed to define it in whatever way suits the problem at hand.

Comment: Yes fair enough. It is down to semantics really - but I wondered if there was a mathematical definition.

Comment: @JonHolland I think it can be understood variius ways (linguistic asoect) but that many of those might be translatable into mathematical definitions. I might add a few if I think of them and have the energy.

Comment: @JonHolland For example we could perhaps decide "they had a wide variety of incomes" means "the standard deviation in their incomes was at least double what it is for the general population".

Comment: yes that is an interesting line of thought

Comment: @JonHolland When people use a phrase they do usually mean *something*, and it can be interesting finding a way to express ir. :-)